# Flask, and valid json - ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

Tags: python, flask

Here is my flask code using restful.

```
def get(self):
    data = [{"id": "2", "lags": [{"id": "GBPQ1"}, {"id": "GBPQ2"},{"id": "GBPQ3"}, {"id": "BPQ4"}], "name": "GBP"}]
    return jsonify(data)
```

Here is my error:   Why?  Its valid json per jsoinlint.  How do I resolve?

curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/test/model/exposure/currencies/

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/test/model/exposure/currencies/111111
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- We need to make sure this has a favicon so that the debugger does not by
         accident trigger a request to /favicon.ico which might change the application
         state. -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=console.png">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=debugger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var TRACEBACK = 140493007176848,
          CONSOLE_MODE = false,
          EVALEX = true,
          SECRET = "hIZ55a7qO5d1PpF7ILd6";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="debugger">
<h1>ValueError</h1>
<div class="detail">
  <p class="errormsg">ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required</p>
</div>
<h2 class="traceback">Traceback <em>(most recent call last)</em></h2>
<div class="traceback">

  <ul><li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007176784">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1836</em>,
      in <code class="function">__call__</code></h4>
  <pre>return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177104">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1820</em>,
      in <code class="function">wsgi_app</code></h4>
  <pre>response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177168">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">271</em>,
      in <code class="function">error_router</code></h4>
  <pre>return original_handler(e)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007176912">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">271</em>,
      in <code class="function">error_router</code></h4>
  <pre>return original_handler(e)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007176976">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">188</em>,
      in <code class="function">wrapped_function</code></h4>
  <pre>return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177296">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1403</em>,
      in <code class="function">handle_exception</code></h4>
  <pre>reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177424">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">268</em>,
      in <code class="function">error_router</code></h4>
  <pre>return self.handle_error(e)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177360">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1817</em>,
      in <code class="function">wsgi_app</code></h4>
  <pre>response = self.full_dispatch_request()</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177552">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1477</em>,
      in <code class="function">full_dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <pre>rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177616">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">271</em>,
      in <code class="function">error_router</code></h4>
  <pre>return original_handler(e)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177232">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">271</em>,
      in <code class="function">error_router</code></h4>
  <pre>return original_handler(e)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177488">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">188</em>,
      in <code class="function">wrapped_function</code></h4>
  <pre>return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177744">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1381</em>,
      in <code class="function">handle_user_exception</code></h4>
  <pre>reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177872">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">268</em>,
      in <code class="function">error_router</code></h4>
  <pre>return self.handle_error(e)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177808">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1475</em>,
      in <code class="function">full_dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <pre>rv = self.dispatch_request()</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007178000">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1461</em>,
      in <code class="function">dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <pre>return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007178064">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">477</em>,
      in <code class="function">wrapper</code></h4>
  <pre>resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177680">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">84</em>,
      in <code class="function">view</code></h4>
  <pre>return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007177936">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">587</em>,
      in <code class="function">dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <pre>resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007178128">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/ubuntu/workspace/qtaapi/qtaapi/resources/model_exposure_currencies.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">198</em>,
      in <code class="function">get</code></h4>
  <pre>return jsonify(data)</pre>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140493007178192">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">237</em>,
      in <code class="function">jsonify</code></h4>
  <pre>return current_app.response_class(dumps(dict(*args, **kwargs),</pre>
</div>
</ul>
  <blockquote>ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="plain">
  <form action="/?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=paste" method="post">
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="language" value="pytb">
      This is the Copy/Paste friendly version of the traceback.  <span
      class="pastemessage">You can also paste this traceback into
      a <a href="https://gist.github.com/">gist</a>:
      <input type="submit" value="create paste"></span>
    </p>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="code" readonly>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 188, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 188, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 587, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/qtaapi/qtaapi/resources/model_exposure_currencies.py", line 198, in get
    return jsonify(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py", line 237, in jsonify
    return current_app.response_class(dumps(dict(*args, **kwargs),
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required</textarea>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="explanation">
  The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application.  You can now
  look at the traceback which led to the error.  <span class="nojavascript">
  If you enable JavaScript you can also use additional features such as code
  execution (if the evalex feature is enabled), automatic pasting of the
  exceptions and much more.</span>
</div>
      <div class="footer">
        Brought to you by <strong class="arthur">DON'T PANIC</strong>, your
        friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!--

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 188, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 188, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 587, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/qtaapi/qtaapi/resources/model_exposure_currencies.py", line 198, in get
    return jsonify(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py", line 237, in jsonify
    return current_app.response_class(dumps(dict(*args, **kwargs),
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

-->
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.ssh$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to give a dictionary to jsonify :

```
def get(self):
    data = [{"id": "2", "lags": [{"id": "GBPQ1"}, {"id": "GBPQ2"},{"id": "GBPQ3"}, {"id": "BPQ4"}], "name": "GBP"}]
    return jsonify({'data': data})
```

Or you can also do that if you prefer: `return jsonify(data=data)`